# problem with Search module in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I've problem with the search module in drupal. When I do a seach, it return 0 results even-though there are patterns matching. I ran the cron manually and flushed the cache. Now, the search module works fine.

I wanna know whether I should do this procedure regularly for the search module to work?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clearing cache is not need, running cron is main
read here how to do: http://drupal.org/cron

Comment: if you don't like command line setups, just install and configure poormanscron: http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron

Comment: so, withour running cron, the search won't fetch results from latest posts?

Comment: @Sam: Yup, the search index gets build on cron runs only, so no correct search results without cron! (this also means that it can take some time before new content shows up in search results, depending how often your cron.php gets called and how much new content was added in the meantime - for huge amounts of new content, it can take several cron cycles till the indexing is complete)